# Insert string inside a string

Tags: c#, string, insert

Okay, this really should be simple and I have no idea why it is not working. When I try and use the Insert method for string it appears to do nothing.

```
                MonthAge = mAge.ToString();

                newLine = rl.Substring(0, rl.Length);
                newLine.Insert(32, MonthAge + ",");  //doesnt do anything
                newLine.Insert(0, "DOSOMETHING");   //doesnt do anything
```

I'm sure there's a simple solution but after browsing a few threads I couldn't find it.

Comment: If duplicate question does not provide enough information consider searching http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+string+insert+immutable fr similar posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are not mutuable in C#. `Insert` returns a new string instead of modifying the existing one.

This should work:

```
newLine = newLine.Insert(32, MonthAge + ",");
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't assigning the return value to anything - .NET strings are immutable, `Insert` returns a new instance of `string`.

Comment: Thanks, like I said, easy fix. :)